# Is it normal for iCloud's iOS "Manage Storage" settings to show the CONTENTS of file packages instead of the package names?

Tags: ios, icloud

My app uses custom file packages (UTI conforms to com.apple.package) to store individual "notebooks", each package (directory) containing various individual files. I would expect the "Manage Storage" section of iCloud settings on my iPad to show the names of the packages, NOT the contents of these packages. It makes more sense for the user to be able to delete an entire "notebook" instead of the component files inside.

So is this normal, or did I do something wrong when I uploaded the package to iCloud? I've created and exported the UTI for my custom file type (and it seems to work, since the email app recognizes my new files and associates them with my app). Do I somehow have to tell iCloud about my UTI definition?

Finally, if this behavior is "normal", is there a way to force it to work like I want it to?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think I discovered the answer by accident. I recently deleting all the iCloud data for my app from the iCloud settings -> Manage Storage page (by tapping "Edit" and then "Delete All"). After reloading my data back up to iCloud, it worked as I expected - I now see just the package filename, instead of all the contents of the package.

I suspect this is because I originally uploaded my data to iCloud before I properly defined the UTI. After I finished getting the UTI correct, I had my app delete the data and reload it, but this apparently wasn't as thorough as deleting the entire iCloud container via the "Manage Storage" page. My best guess is that when I FULLY deleted everything and reloaded it from scratch, the proper UTI export data went with it this time.

Anyway, it now works! I hope this can help someone else in a similar situation.